# How to get all the sockets connected to Socket.io

Tags: socket.io

I did some search here and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956637/socket-io-how-to-get-different-active-user-lists-for-different-endpoints-rooms) answer

```
// list all connected sockets
    var list = io.sockets.sockets;
    console.log("Connected sockets:");
    list.forEach(function(s) {
        console.log("    socket.id = ", s.id);
    });
```

But because `io.sockets.sockets;` that mentioned there is NOT an array it doesn't work.so i have 2 questions :

a)How can i access to all sockets connected?

b)How can i access to sockets connected to specific room?

Cheers

PS:this question is asked before but those questions are out dated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In latest version of socket.io (1.4.5) you'l have to do

```
Object.keys(io.sockets.sockets);
```

This returns an array containing id's of sockets connected and you can apply forEach on it.

```
Object.keys(io.sockets.sockets).forEach(function(id) {
    console.log("ID:",id)  // socketId
})
```

Ok now for the B part, for getting array of socketids off sockets connected to a room use

```
Object.keys(io.sockets.adapter.rooms["ROOM_NAME"].sockets) //returns array of socketId's
```

Comment: Thanks but it gives me TypeError: list.forEach is not a function i can copy the full error if is needed.

Comment: can you add the list object you are getting? Maybe its got something to do with the socket,io version you're using. For me "io.sockets.sockets" returns an array of objects. So list.forEach works well and i'm getting the socketId's. Btw i checked this in socket.io version 1.3.5

Comment: Turns out i was right. It was a version problem. I have modified my answer

Comment: wow thanks man! so final code will be like this : var list = io.sockets.sockets;
 console.log("Connected sockets:")
 Object.keys(io.sockets.sockets).forEach(function(id) {
    console.log("ID:",id)  // socketId     plseas edit your question and only reamin the correct part so i can choose yours as the right question.

Comment: btw the B part of question is unanswered

Comment: I'l look into the B part now :)

Comment: I have added the answer for the B part of question.

Comment: Thanks i replaced the "ROOM_NAME" with one of my rooms but like this "LOTR" but it gives me 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'sockets' of undefined' should i pass the room as string? Thanks

Comment: I've checked this code and it works. If you get that error it means there is no room "LOTR". Try : console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms). This shows all rooms..
See if the result contains your room.

Comment: And yes the room name should be a string: ["LOTR"]

Comment: It prints `[object Object]`  as room name.would you like to enable the chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102843/discussion-between-nijeesh-and-mojtaba).