# socket.emit not firing inside post request

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I wrapped `io.on('connection', function (socket) {` in a post request. I then call `socket.emit('news', 'username taken');` within the post request. For some reason when I make this call it sends nothing to the client. When I change the emit to `io.emit('connection', function (socket))` It works and sends the data to the client. My problem with that solution is using io.emit would send the data to all the sockets that are connected. My question is how can I use socket.emit within this post request.

```
io.on('connection', onConnection);

function onConnection(sock) {
 sock.emit('news', 'username is taken');
}

app.post('/signup', function(req, res) {

    var userDetails = User({
        firstname: req.body.firstname,
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password1, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10))
    });

    User.findOne({
        $or: [ { 'username': req.body.username}, {'email': req.body.email}]
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (user) {
              if(user.username === req.body.username){
              onConnection();
              console.log('username is taken');
            } else {
            }
            if(user.email === req.body.email){
              console.log('email is taken')
            } else {
            }
        } else {
          userDetails.save(function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
          });
          res.redirect('/');
          console.log('change to login')
        }
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
    });

   });

});
```

Comment: Eeeck.  Don't put an `app.post()` inside an `io.on()` EVER.  This is just wrong.  Your `app.post()` handler will be available to ALL incoming requests that match that route and you will add a new duplicate handler for every single user that connects, and all the `app.post()`  handlers will get called for every single user.  There's no way, this is ever correct.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, I was wondering about that as well.

Comment: I see you changed things, but you can't put `io.on('connection', ...)` inside your `app.post()` either.  That will create duplicate handlers for that event.  Go back to the beginning and describe in words exactly what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: No, that doesn't work either.  See my previous comment.

Comment: Please stop guessing at code.  You can't call `onConnection()` with no arguments and expect it to work in your latest incarnation.  Please describe exactly what you're trying to do in words and then we can help you.  If the goal is to send a socket.io message to the user who made the `app.post()` request, then please just describe that in words and we can offer some ideas for how to do that.

Comment: I want to send a socket.io message when a username has been found in the database. The if statement that checks for an existing user is the if(user.username === req.body.username){ ect.

Comment: do you want to a) reply to a user initiating an http request or b) you want to send a message to some other service connected to your http server keeping track of things? if your answer is a. then your approach is fundamentally wrong and you should just use http response to signal the result of an action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way you would approach this is you would use session middleware that would establish a user session when the first page on the site was loaded.  Then, when the user connects with socket.io, you would put the `socket.id` into the session for that user.  Then, when you get the `app.post()` and you want to send to their socket.io connection, you would look in the session for that user, get the `socket.id` for that user and then look up the socket using that.  Once you have the socket, you can send a message to them.

You use the session to connect the socket.io connection and the `app.post()`.  no event handlers are set inside another event handler.

Comment: I guess I am going to need to create socket id's for each unique user that connects.

Comment: @JohnAnderson - socket.io already has `socket.id` for you to use when they connect.  And, you can use that id to find the socket in the socket.io data structures later when you need to send to that user.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed my problem. What I did was create a variable called socket1. Then I assigned the socket parameter to socket1 within the io.on annonymous function. I then have socket as a universal variable that I can call wherever I want in my code. I'm not sure if this is programatically correct but it works.

```
var SOCKET_LIST = {};

var socket1;

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    SOCKET_LIST[socket.id] = socket;
    socket1 = socket;
    socket.emit('news', 'username taken');
});

app.post('/signup', function(req, res) {

var userDetails = User({
    firstname: req.body.firstname,
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password1, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10))
});

User.findOne({
    $or: [ { 'username': req.body.username}, {'email': req.body.email}]
}, function(err, user) {
    if (user) {
        if(user.username === req.body.username){
          socket1.emit('news', 'username taken');
          console.log('username is taken');
        } else {
        }
        if(user.email === req.body.email){
          io.emit('news', 'email taken');
          console.log('email is taken')
        } else {
        }
    } else {
      userDetails.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
      res.redirect('/');
      console.log('change to login')
    }
    if (err) {
        return done(err);
    }
});

});
```

Comment: This solution will only work for a web site that has only one user.  As soon as your second user connects, it will not work.  See my answer for a general approach to a solution.

Comment: I updated my answer in regards to @jfriend00 answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 do you think something like this would be viable?

Comment: You don't need to do `SOCKET_LIST[socket.id] = socket;`.  `io.sockets.connected` is already an index by `socket.id` - maintained automatically by socket.io.  Plus your scheme leaks socket objects because you never remove sockets from the data structure.

Comment: If I already have socket.id indexed how could I search for a specific user, that is connected?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956637/socket-io-how-to-get-different-active-user-lists-for-different-endpoints-rooms/32957983#32957983 for some doc on various socket.io data structures.

Comment: To connect an http request with the matching socket.io connection, you will need something that is cookie based.  I recommended you use a session manager for your web server which would automatically give you a session object for each browser connecting to your server and you could then get access to that session when a socket.io connection is created and set the socket.id in to that session.  That would then give you access to the socket.id from `app.post()` which would allow you to find the right socket.io connection for that user.    FYI, `socket.handshake.headers.cookie` is cookies.